# Как сделать выемку в линии на css?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать такую линюю на css?

Comment: вставить повернутый квадрат в псевдоселектор

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
div {
 height:10px;
 width:300px;
 margin:0 auto;
 border-bottom:3px solid purple;
 position:relative;
}

div:after{
content:'';
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  bottom:-13px;
  transform:rotate(45deg) translateX(-50%);
  border-bottom:3px solid purple;
  border-right:3px solid purple;
  background-color:#fff;
  
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```